# mysql query unsigned -unsigned error

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `int1` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `int2` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

if `int1` is bigger than `int2` ,the result of executing "select (`int1`-`int2`) as int3 from t1" is error  !  Who can help me ?Thanks!

Comment: Which error you are getting?...post error also

Answer (score 0):

`BIGINT UNSIGNED` is unsigned and cannot be negative.

Your expression `int1-int2` will use a negative intermediate value if `int1` is less than `int2`.

You should implicitly converted to SIGNED.Try this;)

```
select CAST(`int1`AS SIGNED) - CAST(`int2`AS SIGNED) as `int3` from t1
```